# Rubiks cube warping

Tags: rubiks-cube

[image]
Why do all my cubes twist or warp like this?

Comment: I suspect because you warped them intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Like this. All I did was to stagger the twists a little, and force some part twists in another direction. Although this cube is old, it's still quite tight and in good condition.

[image]